# Java application getting launched when trying to generate a thumbnail from a image byte array

Tags: java, bufferedimage

[image: demo]

Code:

```
public byte[] getThumbnail(byte[] imageBytes) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Thumbnails.of(inputStream).size(50, 50).keepAspectRatio(true)
            .outputFormat("jpg").toOutputStream(outputStream);
    byte[] picture = outputStream.toByteArray();
    return picture;
}
```

I am trying to generate a thumbnail from an image in the above code.

When I call the above function, it launches a Java icon, which is shown in my attached screenshot. If I try to close this icon, my application gets closed.

Comment: Can you please provide the context in which you are calling the method?

Comment: I guess i have already written that in my post above, i am trying to generate a thumbnail for a given image. I have a byte[] array of a image, and i need a byte[] for a thumbnail.

Comment: I tried to debug the code, the java icon is getting launched at : 
`Thumbnails.of(inputStream).size(50, 50).keepAspectRatio(true)
            .outputFormat("jpg").toOutputStream(outputStream); `

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dock icon appears, because some of the imaging code you use, use `awt` under the hoods. This triggers the dock icon to appear on OS X. It's possible to suppress the icon, though.

The cross platform way of doing it, is running you application in "headless" mode, that is, with no user interaction using mouse, keyboard or screen feedback (ie. windows). You can specify headless mode at startup, using the system property `java.awt.headless` on the command line like this:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Alternatively, in code like this:

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

For OS X (and an Apple JRE) you can alternatively use the system property `apple.awt.UIElement`, it will suppress the dock icon only, but otherwise let your app use windows etc.:

```
java -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true
```

[From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/Java_PropertiesRef/Articles/JavaSystemProperties.html):

> Suppresses the normal application Dock icon and menu bar from appearing. Only appropriate for background applications which show a tray icon or other alternate user interface for accessing the apps windows. Unlike `java.awt.headless=true`, this does not suppress windows and dialogs from actually appearing on screen.
>   The default value is `false`.